# how to get same header and footer for all web pages of my website

Tags: php, html, css

header does not stick to one place for all web pages,it keep changing the position. building website using html,css and php, thought of using iframes but went for php. included
`<?php include 'header.php';?>` just below the body tag, stil header keep changes in pages,

htmlcode is below:`enter code here`

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 

href="headerstyle.css"/></head>
<body>

<div id="header">

<a href="https://twitter.com" title="Follow Me on Twitter" 

class="twitter social-slide" target="_blank"></a>

<a href="https://facebook.com" title="Follow Me on Facebook" 

class="facebook social-slide" target="_blank"></a>

<a href="https://plus.google.com" title="Follow Me on 

Google+" class="google plus social-slide" 

target="_blank"></a>

<a href="https://linkedin.com" title="Follow Me on Linkedin" 

class="linkedin social-slide" target="_blank"></a>


<div class="company">

<h1> Tech Processor</h1>
</div>

<div class="tagline">


<h5>We Grow with Technology</h5>
</div>



<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li class="logo"><a href="https://index.htm"><img 

src="images/home.png" border="0" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Insights</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li class="search"><a><input type="text" 

value="Search" onclick="(this.value=='Search' ? this.value = 

'' : null)" /></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>




<div class="contact">
<a href="form.html"/contact" class="contact 

pNav">Enquiry</a>
</div>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

css code:

```
{

width,body,div,h1,h2,h3,width,padding,margin,height

}

html

{

height:170%

}

body

{

background-color:#79a2ff;


}

#header 

{
  background-color:#ffffff;
  height:125px;
  width:1372px;
  margin-left:-8px;
}


.company

{

  color:#acacac;
  padding-top:20px;
  padding-left:40px;
  margin-left:-1%;
  margin-top:-1% 



}

.tagline
{
  margin-top:-2%;
  margin-left:5%;
  padding:2px;
  positon:fixed;

}


.social-slide {

    height: 48px;
    width: 48px;
    margin:15px 5px 0px 10px;
    float: right;
    -webkit-transition: all ease 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all ease 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all ease 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: all ease 0.3s;
    transition: all ease 0.3s;




}
.social-slide:hover {
    background-position: 0px -48px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
.twitter {
    background-image: url('images/twitter.png');
}
.facebook {
    background-image: url('images/facebook.png');
}
.google {
    background-image: url('images/google plus.png');
}

.linkedin {
    background-image: url('images/linkedin.png');
}




a, a:hover, a:active, a:visited, a:visited:hover { text-

decoration: none; border: none; outline: none; }

div.nav {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px auto;
    border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #fff #dfdfdf #dfdfdf #dfdfdf;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    display: table;
}

div.nav ul {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #9f9f9f;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left 

bottom, from(#b3b3b3), to(#6e6e6e));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #b3b3b3,  

#6e6e6e);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient

(startColorstr='#b3b3b3', endColorstr='#6e6e6e');
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
}

div.nav ul li {
    margin: 0px 1px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left 

bottom, from(#cecece), to(#8c8c8c));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #cecece,  

#8c8c8c);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient

(startColorstr='#cecece', endColorstr='#8c8c8c');
    float: left;
}
div.nav ul li:first-child {
    border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
}
div.nav ul li:last-child {
    margin-right: 0px !important;
    border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
}
div.nav ul li a {
    margin: 0px 1px 0px 1px;
    padding: 11px 33px 11px 33px;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left 

bottom, from(#cacaca), to(#848484));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #cacaca,  

#848484);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient

(startColorstr='#cacaca', endColorstr='#848484');
    float: left;
    /*-*/
    font-family: Lucida Sans, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #252525;
    text-shadow: #cecece 0px 1px 0px;
}

div.nav ul li:first-child a {
    border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
}
div.nav ul li:last-child a {
    margin-right: 0px !important;
    border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
}

div.nav ul li:hover {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left 

bottom, from(#999999), to(#5f5f5f));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #999999,  

#5f5f5f);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient

(startColorstr='#999999', endColorstr='#5f5f5f');
}
div.nav ul li:hover a {
    padding: 11px 33px 11px 33px;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left 

bottom, from(#929292), to(#535353));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #929292,  

#535353);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient

(startColorstr='#929292', endColorstr='#535353');
    /*-*/
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: #454545 0px -1px 1px;
}
div.nav ul li:active {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left 

bottom, from(#242424), to(#3f3f3f));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #242424,  

#3f3f3f);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient

(startColorstr='#242424', endColorstr='#3f3f3f');
}
div.nav ul li:active a {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 9px 33px 11px 33px;
    border-width: 2px 1px 0px 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #282928 #3f3f3f #525051 #3f3f3f;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 

.05), inset 0 2px 5px #363636, inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(255, 

255, 255, .1);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05), 

inset 0 2px 5px #363636, inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 

.1);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left 

bottom, from(#999999), to(#5f5f5f));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #999999,  

#5f5f5f);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient

(startColorstr='#999999', endColorstr='#5f5f5f');
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: #454545 0px -1px 1px;
}
div.nav ul li:last-child:active a {
    padding-right: 34px;
}
div.nav ul li.selected {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left 

bottom, from(#242424), to(#3f3f3f));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #242424,  

#3f3f3f);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient

(startColorstr='#242424', endColorstr='#3f3f3f');
}
div.nav ul li.selected a {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 9px 33px 11px 33px;
    border-width: 2px 1px 0px 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #282928 #3f3f3f #525051 #3f3f3f;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left 

bottom, from(#373837), to(#525051));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #373837,  

#525051);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient

(startColorstr='#373837', endColorstr='#525051');
    /*-*/
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: #454545 0px -1px 1px;
}
div.nav ul li.selected:last-child a {
    padding-right: 34px;
}

/*-----*/

div.nav ul li.logo a {
    padding: 5px 34px 7px 34px;
}
div.nav ul li.logo:active a {
    padding: 5px 35px 7px 35px;
    border: none;
}
div.nav ul li.logo a img { width: 24px; height: 24px; }

/*-----*/

div.nav ul li.search a {
    padding: 8px 9px 9px 7px;
}
div.nav ul li.search a input {
    width: 120px;
    height: 17px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
    border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #888 #b0b0b0 #dedede #b0b0b0;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    background: #fff url(button_search.png) no-repeat 5px 

3px;
    /*-*/
    font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", 

Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #7e7e7e;
}
div.nav ul li.search:hover, div.nav ul li.search:active {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left 

bottom, from(#cecece), to(#8c8c8c));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #cecece,  

#8c8c8c);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient

(startColorstr='#cecece', endColorstr='#8c8c8c');
}
div.nav ul li.search:hover a, div.nav ul li.search:active a 

{
    margin: 0px 1px 0px 1px;
    border: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left 

bottom, from(#cacaca), to(#848484));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #cacaca,  

#848484);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient

(startColorstr='#cacaca', endColorstr='#848484');
}
div.nav ul li.search:active a {
    padding: 8px 9px 9px 7px;
}


.contact
{
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-webkit-background-clip: border-box;
-webkit-background-origin: padding-box;
-webkit-background-size: auto;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgb(0, 138, 255);
background-attachment: scroll;
background-clip: border-box;
background-color:#79a2ff;
background-image: none;
background-origin: padding-box;
background-size: auto;
border-bottom-color: rgb(92, 144, 188);
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-bottom-width: 1px;
border-image-outset: 0px;
border-image-repeat: stretch;
border-image-slice: 100%;
border-image-source: none;
border-image-width: 1;
border-left-color: rgb(92, 144, 188);
border-left-style: solid;
border-left-width: 1px;
border-right-color: rgb(92, 144, 188);
border-right-style: solid;
border-right-width: 1px;
border-top-color: rgb(92, 144, 188);
border-top-style: solid;
border-top-width: 1px;
color:#ffffff;
cursor: pointer
display: block;
font-size: 16px;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
height: 20px;
letter-spacing: normal;
line-height: 20px;
opacity: 0.800000011920929;

right: 134.890625px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
text-shadow: rgb(0, 0, 0) 0px 1px 2px;
text-transform: uppercase;
top: 70px;
right:0px;
width: 100px;
position: fixed;
word-spacing: 0px;
z-index: 15;

}
```

Comment: what is the output of `header.php`? What do you mean by 'it keeps changing position'? does it rotate? does it jump to the bottom? does it move 1 pixel every second? Does it fly to the moon? and back?

Comment: tried to add the code,keep showing me error,i guess this is not for new developers,this is being designed for brilliant developers,who can easily find the solution,i have tried to add code four time, put the four space as well, but i dont know wht it requires

Comment: @KumarKatariya: It should be simple. Paste your code, highlight it, Ctrl+K. That's all there to it.

Comment: @AmalMurali thank you so much i just did it :)

Comment: @KumarKatariya If you're using PHP to only include files but will not be using the "power" of PHP, you can name your files as `.shtml` and use an `<!--#include virtual="/includes/file.shtml" -->` because I see no PHP in your code. You will get the same effect, minus the power. ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii-i havnt used anything as php in the code, simple html and css,but i am going into the internal page of website,the header elements changes its position, i tired to find the solution, and i found if i just include <?php include 'header.php';?> in every page where i need to include the header, and just name the file name from html to php,it will work,, as php  can understand the html language as well..

Comment: @KumarKatariya If you wish your header to remain in one place, you need to have `position:fixed;` in your `#header` in CSS, plus you'll need to close your `</div>` after `class="linkedin social-slide" target="_blank"></a>` for `<div id="header">` it is unclosed and will cause you problems.

Comment: @Fred-ii-i have did the same, but nothing changes, my header still changes in every web pages..

Comment: @KumarKatariya Your CSS opening with `{` is incorrect, unless you had trouble pasting it. Can you elaborate on "my header still changes in every web pages"?

Comment: @Fred-ii-i have made header.html,, and i want to use the same header for all my internal pages,but it shows correct on the home page, but when i click on the Enquiry button, it is taking me internal page but header elements completely changes(name of the company,logo,social icons,)these all changes there place, someone goes hide, some company name overlap the tag line of the company, div header does not stay alike for all internal pages

Comment: @KumarKatariya I don't know what it could be. Any way of knowing the site URL? Maybe you're not including your stylesheet in all your pages, could be a number of things. Plus, you're using class for elements that should be IDs.

Comment: @KumarKatariya I also noticed all your links for example `<li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>` are `#`. Are you not linking to files? You should be doing `<li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>` if `contact.html` is the name of your page. And this `<a href="form.html"/contact"` is incorrect. It should be `<a href="form.html" class="contact pNav">Enquiry</a>` yet you do not have a class called `pNav` in your CSS.

Comment: @KumarKatariya You're also using `onclick="(this.value=='Search'` which I find no JS associated with. Your structure needs to be reworked. I suggest you stop right now, and re-think this over. I cannot spend any more time than I already have, I must now get on with my day. I wish you well, cheers.

Answer (score 2):

If you use this structure:

some page.php:

```
<html>
  <head>..</head>
  <body>
    <?php include('header.php'); ?>
      <div> ..body content.. </div>
    <?php include('footer.php'); ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

and you include the same header and footer on every page, you're set. 
Just ensure that the includes are included in a consistent manner on all pages. Not much to it.

If you still have positioning issues, there might be something going on in your css or html structure.

Update:
you might want to fix this too:

```
<a href="form.html"/contact" class="contact 

pNav">Enquiry</a>
```

Comment: where to add below code:<?php include('header.php'); ?>
      <div> ..body content.. </div>
    <?php include('footer.php'); ?> i have coded everything in html,, should i need to change the extension to php? and i guess i need to include the <?php include('footer.php'); after body tag right?

Comment: @KumarKatariya Your index file and all other files having the above structure, need to have the `.php` file extension in order for it to work, but I don't know why you're using PHP to only "include" files, when you can use SHTML instead, which is simply `.html` with an added `s` to be `.shtml` works just as well.

Comment: @KumarKatariya, yes you can change the extension to php. It ensures your host properly parses the page (if it thinks it is regular HTML, it will not parse the PHP in it!) See of it as a template. Add the header just below <body> and footer just above </body> (so *not* after body tag). Everything between the two includes is your page content.